# Trying to update text (specifically health of a boss in a game) and getting "exc_bad_instruction (code=exc_i386_invop subcode=0x0)"

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Relevant code:

import SpriteKit

class GameScene: SKScene {

```
//1
let warrior = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "warr")

var healthBoss = SKLabelNode(text: "Boss HP: 25")

override func didMove(to view: SKView){
    gameScene = self
    //2
    setupLayers()


    spawnWarr(at: warriorposition)
    spawnBoss(at: bossposition)

    setupLabels()

    backgroundColor = SKColor.blue




}


func setupLayers() {
    objectsLayer = SKNode()
    objectsLayer.name = "Objects Layer"
    addChild(objectsLayer)
}


func spawnWarr(at: CGPoint) {

    let newWarr = warriorclass()
    newWarr.position = at
    self.addChild(newWarr)

}

func spawnBoss(at: CGPoint) {

    let newBoss = bossclass()
    newBoss.position = at
    self.addChild(newBoss)

}

func setupLabels() {

    healthBoss.position = CGPoint(x: size.width * 0.5, y: size.height * 0.1)
    healthBoss.fontColor = whiteColor
    healthBoss.fontName = "Copperplate"
    healthBoss.text = "Boss HP: \(spawnedBoss.health)"
```

\ Specifically here using (spawnedBoss.health) is where I get "exc_bad_instruction (code=exc_i386_invop subcode=0x0)"

```
    healthBoss.fontSize = 22
    healthBoss.zPosition = layers.uistuff
    objectsLayer.addChild(healthBoss)

}
```

bossclass.swift file -

import UIKit
import SpriteKit

class bossclass: character, pTargetable {

```
var health = 25
var maxhealth = 25

override init() {


    super.init()

    scorePoints = 5

    let texture = texturesBoss
    let xSize = texture.size().width*bossscale
    let ySize = texture.size().height*bossscale
    let size = CGSize(width: xSize, height: ySize)

    self.name = "boss"

    let top = SKSpriteNode (texture: texture, size: size)
    top.zPosition = layers.raiders
    top.color = SKColor(red: 1.0, green: 1.0, blue: 1.0, alpha: 1.0)
    top.colorBlendFactor = 1.0

    self.addChild(top)

}


required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

func takeDamage(damage: Int) {
    health -= damage
    print("You lost \(damage) hit points")

    if health <= 0 {
        die()
        print("You are dead now")
    }
}
```

}

global.swift file includes:
var spawnedBoss: bossclass!

and protocol:

protocol pTargetable {

```
var health: Int { get set }
func takeDamage(damage: Int)
```

}

So the issue from what I can see is there is a nil. I thought maybe I was referencing the boss' health before I spawned the boss, but looking at the code it doesn't seem that way. Maybe there is an easier solution to having a boss health bar that updates with damage?

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

When you wrote:

```
var spawnedBoss: bossclass!
```

You promised Swift that you would never try to use spawnedBoss if it was nil and that it shouldn't force you to check.

Then you wrote:

```
healthBoss.text = "Boss HP: \(spawnedBoss.health)"
```

And at this point `spawnedBoss` is probably nil.

So, I would change:

```
var spawnedBoss: bossclass!
```

to

```
var spawnedBoss: bossclass?
```

And then add in all of the proper checking for nil to clear the compiler errors you are going to get.  When you clear them all (not with !, but with `if let` or ??), then you can be sure that you are using spawnedBoss only when it's not nil.